# How can I show an error message when input field is not filled, checked or selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calculator

I'm trying to build a calorie calculator for my website. I was trying to show an error / warning message when fields are not filled. For example: when attività lavorativa is not selected and the calculate button is clicked, a message appears warning the user that the radio has not been selected. I wish I could do the same thing with input type number fields, I don't know if this requires something different for each field.

I have no idea what the function is, I'm a fan and have no programming skills. Please, help!

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/89wtnxj4/273/

```
<!--Input Field-->
<label class="mts-label">Peso</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="weight" name"weight1" placeholder="es: 70Kg"/>

<label class="mts-label">Altezza</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="3" id="height" name"height1" placeholder="es: 170cm"/>

<label class="mts-label">Età</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="age" name"age1" placeholder="es: 25 anni"/>

<label class="mts-label">Bodyfat in %</label>
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="bodyfat" name"bodyfat1" placeholder="es: 15%"/>

<div class="mts-label">Sesso</div>

<!--Radio Button Sex-->
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexuomo">Uomo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mts-radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexdonna">Donna</label>
  </div>
  
  <!--Radio Activity Level-->
  <br>
 
  <label class="mts-label">Attività lavorativa</label>
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="leggero" name="radiosa" value="1.2" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="leggero">Leggero</label>
  </div>
  
   <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="attivo" name="radiosa" value="1.375" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="attivo">Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="allenato" name="radiosa" value="1.55" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="allenato">Allenato</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Mattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.75" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Mattivo">Molto Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Eattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.9" onclick="calculate()">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Eattivo">Estremamente Attivo</label>
  </div>

<!---BMR Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>


<div id="bmr-sexuomo" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_man" name="bmr_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="bmr-sexdonna" hidden>
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_woman" name="bmr_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor Formula</label><br>
<div id="MifflinMale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Male</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_man" name="tdee_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal Uomo" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<div id="MifflinFemale" hidden> 
<label class="mts-label">Female</label><br>
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_woman" name="tdee_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal donna" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_katch" name="bmr_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_katch" name="tdee_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_cunningham" name="bmr_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_cunningham" name="tdee_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---Calc & Reset Button--->
<br>
<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Re-Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

---

```
 // Calc-Function
calculate = function()
{
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var bodyfat = document.getElementById('bodyfat').value / 100;
    var ActivityLevel = document.querySelector('input[name="radiosa"]:checked').value;
    
//Sex Selection Hide-Show Div// 

var sex = document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value;
document.getElementById('bmr-sexuomo').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('bmr-sexdonna').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
document.getElementById('MifflinMale').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
document.getElementById('MifflinFemale').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
    
var bmr_mifflin_man = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) + 5;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = bmr_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_man = (bmr_mifflin_man*ActivityLevel);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_man').value = tdee_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var bmr_mifflin_woman = (10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) - 161;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_woman').value = bmr_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

var tdee_mifflin_woman = (bmr_mifflin_woman*ActivityLevel);
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_woman').value = tdee_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";


 //Result BMR Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var bmr_katch = (370 + ( 21.6 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var tdee_katch = (bmr_katch*ActivityLevel); 
document.getElementById('tdee_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result BMR Cunningham Formula
    var bmr_cunningham = (500 + ( 22 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//Result TDEE Cunningham Formula
    var tdee_cunningham = (bmr_cunningham*ActivityLevel); 
document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham.toLocaleString('it-IT', {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal";

//This is Activity Level Radio Selection//
 var leggero = document.getElementById('leggero').value * 1.2;
 var attivo = document.getElementById('attivo').value * 1.375;
 var allenato = document.getElementById('allenato').value * 1.55;
 var Mattivo = document.getElementById('Mattivo').value * 1.75;
 var Eattivo = document.getElementById('Eattivo').value * 1.9;
 
}

//Reset Function
function resetFields(){
    var inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    inputArray.forEach(function (input){
        input.value = "";
    });
}

//Error Message

??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on `keyup` `blur` `change` etc then check each fields value if it is not empty.

```
$(function(){
   // iterate on any input that has the classname `required`
   $.each($('input.required'), function(){
      // run a function every time the element's keyup event is fired
      $(this).on('keyup', function(){
        let value = $(this).val()
        if (value.trim() === '') {
            // or add error class
            // $(this).addClass('invalid')
            $(this).css({ 'border' : '1px solid red !important' });
        } else {
            // $(this).removeClass('invalid')
            $(this).css({ 'border' : 'none' });
        }
      })
   })
})
```

For a quick example, the script above will listen on an input with the class `.required`'s change event and if the value is empty, it will add a border colored red.

- Note, this requires `Jquery`

Comment: I would recommend using a CSS class and add/remove such class in JS when checking your input. Your JS would look like `document.getElementById('weight').classList.add("invalid")` if the input is invalid, and your CSS would be `input.invalid { border: 1px solid red }`. You can remove that class with `document.getElementById('weight').classList.remove("invalid")`. It's easier to maintain and spread throughout your entire project. If tomorrow you decide to change the style of invalid inputs on your entire site, you just update that one line in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks @Will that was the better approach. I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried with your advice tips but it doesn't work. I don't understand how and where to insert the code. Currently I only do tests on jsfiddle and do not implement anything on the website. I also updated the question above because I realized I have pasted the html twice instead of pasting the js code

Comment: See quick example from your own fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/or9fkad2/